# How to get a global location from MouseDown?

Tags: winforms, onmousedown

I'm working on a WinForms app and need to record the location of MouseDown and MouseUp events. My problem is that the events happen on different controls so their coordinate systems don't match (all I need is the amount of drag). I tried adding in the location of the sending control but it still doesn't work right.

*Is there a simple solution to this?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) method for the purpose. Your mouse handler code could then look like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    Control control = (Control) sender;
    Point pointOnScreen = control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    ...
}
```

Comment: That seems to do what I want, but I still have problems... in the rest of the code :b